# .keystore file location of digital signature

Tags: java, digital-signature

I am trying to sign an XML file digitally on server side after uploading. To do this I need the key store alias of the file. From Google what I found in sample codes that the .keystore file is needed to do that. In sample codes they have used a hard coded path. Where will I get this? I have a token (digital signature) and after inserting it the browser is importing the certificate attributes. But I have no idea where the .keystore file is. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a KeyStore using the Java keytool. The keytool is contained in your JREs/JDKs bin folder.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/ggfen/index.html) is a how-to for creating a .keystore file.

Comment: Yes you are right. But, here I have to input all attributes of the certificate into command prompt and that will generate the key store file. Can I generate it through java code? because user will use his token to sign and I have to generate it.

Comment: Yes you can create it programmatically too. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312559/how-do-i-programmatically-create-a-new-keystore) should help you.