# how to extract private key from .p12 file using java sun security

Tags: java, security, private-key

This is my program. I am getting the error "error opening the key file". Kindly help me where i am going wrong.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.util.Base64;

public class ExtractionClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       String  p12Password = "PassWord";
       try{
       FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Aarti_Jangid/Desktop/p12/certChain.p12");
       System.out.println("FILE "+ file);
       KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "SunJSSE");
       keystore.load(file, p12Password.toCharArray());
       String alias = keystore.aliases().nextElement(); 
       PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey)keystore.getKey(alias, p12Password.toCharArray());
       System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key.getEncoded()));
       } catch(KeyStoreException kse) {
           kse.printStackTrace();
           System.err.println("Error getting the key");  
       } catch (Exception e) {
              System.err.println("Error opening the key file");
              e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
}
```

StackTrace:

FILE java.io.FileInputStream@659e0bfd Error opening the key file java.util.NoSuchElementException at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(Unknown Source) at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator.next(Unknown Source) at java.util.Collections$3.nextElement(Unknown Source) at ExtractionCode.ExtractionClass.main(ExtractionClass.java:17) Stack Trace is like that. I am giving the correct password and if i remove String alias = keystore.aliases().nextElement(); then it is giving keyStoreException - uninitialized keystore

Comment: Please copy paste the stack trace here as well

Comment: I think your .p12 file has something wrong, if you use a valid certificate your code works, [here](https://itv.mit-xperts.com/clientssl/issue/dload/index.php?id=1411134668) you can find a valid certificate.

Comment: If you create the .p12 file programmatically, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312559/how-do-i-programmatically-create-a-new-keystore)

Answer (score 0):

I assume your stack trace is :

```
Error opening registry key 'C:/Users/Aarti_Jangid/Desktop/p12/certChain.p12'
Error: could not find Java.dll
Error: could not find Java 2 Runtime Environment
```

If so try this : [Java Error opening registry key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362037/java-error-opening-registry-key)

Comment: FILE java.io.FileInputStream@659e0bfd
Error opening the key file
java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Collections$3.nextElement(Unknown Source)
 at ExtractionCode.ExtractionClass.main(ExtractionClass.java:17)  Stack Trace is like that. I am giving the correct password and if i remove String alias = keystore.aliases().nextElement();  then it is giving keyStoreException - uninitialized keystore

Comment: I am getting null in the private key.